# When I try to execute my Windows Form in C#, It's blank?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

When I try to execute my windows form application, all I see is a completely white blank form. When I look in my form1.cs[Design] everything looks normal, but not when I run it? I can't see the labels, or the buttons or anything. I've never had this issue before and my InitializeComponent I think is where it should be? Here is my Form1.Designer.Cs, or maybe there's an issue in my form1.cs?

```
partial class Identity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.textBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(278, 0);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(116, 87);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "VÄLKOMMEN!";
            this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(67, 87);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(222, 23);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.label2.Text = "Skriv in ditt namn och personnummer nedan.:";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(67, 181);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(51, 13);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.label3.Text = "Förnamn:";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this.label4.AutoSize = true;
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(63, 217);
            this.label4.Name = "label4";
            this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 13);
            this.label4.TabIndex = 3;
            this.label4.Text = "Efternamn:";
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this.label5.AutoSize = true;
            this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 269);
            this.label5.Name = "label5";
            this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(161, 13);
            this.label5.TabIndex = 4;
            this.label5.Text = "Personummer:(ååååmmdd - xxxx)";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(127, 174);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(127, 210);
            this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
            this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.textBox2.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this.textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 266);
            this.textBox3.Name = "textBox3";
            this.textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(164, 20);
            this.textBox3.TabIndex = 7;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(307, 329);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(87, 51);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 8;
            this.button1.Text = "Kör!";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this.label6.AutoSize = true;
            this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(337, 395);
            this.label6.Name = "label6";
            this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
            this.label6.TabIndex = 9;
            this.label6.Text = "label6";
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 423);
            this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
            this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(492, 296);
            this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 10;
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "\"\"";
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(662, 650);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(116, 69);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 11;
            this.button2.Text = "Avsluta:";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Identity
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1207, 755);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label6);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Name = "Identity";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private EventHandler label1_Click;
    }
}
```

Here I am calling the IntializeComponent in my Form1.cs, I haven't moved it since I started this new program at all.

```
public partial class Identity : Form
    {
        public Identity()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public struct Person 
        {
            public double idok;
            public string fname;
            public string lname;
            public string id;
            public string sex;
            public string year;
            public string fyear;
        }
```

Comment: Does your Form1 in Form1.cs calls InitializeComponent in its constructor?

Comment: @Steve I think so, I haven't really moved it since I started this new program, I've looked at this problem on Google and seen the solutions but nothing sticks out from the ordinary I think, I'm a beginner so maybe I've missed something. can I somehow paste my constructor in a comment? To show how it looks, not the entirety of the form1.cs, but only that part, the beginning.

Comment: What is doing `private EventHandler label1_Click;` inside the form.designer file, among the Fields declarations? Have you tampered with this file in any other way that you're not showing here?

Comment: @Jimi No, I haven't done anything out of the ordinary,  even when I remove it, It's still blank. I've never had this issue before.

Comment: I don't know what *out of the ordinary* means. Someone's *ordinary* may not be the same as someone else's. You have done *something*, just *un-do* it. Do you see, in Solution Explorer, when you select this Form, the same structure that you see in other Forms? If you click the *arrow*, do you see both the `.designer.cs` file and the `.resx` file? Have you changed the name of the class or the file at some point? Other? -- How did that `private EventHandler` thing end up there?

Comment: @Jimi Like I said, I haven't done anything that isn't standard, I haven't tampered with anything unusual. I created the design in form1.cs[design], named labels, text boxes and buttons, and then I created the code for it in form1.cs like ordinary, as simple as anything. I don't see anything unusual in my form1.designer or in my constructor, I pasted it in my question, you can see if anything looks odd because to me it doesn't.

Comment: How did `private EventHandler label1_Click;` end up in the designer file?

Comment: @Jimi good question, even if I remove it, it still stays blank when I execute it.

Comment: You renamed the form. Is this the form that starts when the program starts? If so, go to `Program.cs` and change `Application.Run(new Form1());` to `Application.Run(new Identity());`

Comment: @Jimi I'll take a look at the various things you mentioned, but everything looks normal, I haven't changed the name of the file or anything like that neither for example. Maybe without thinking I've done something wrong, it happens.

Comment: That's not the point. *Something* happened, you did *something*. Otherwise that thing wouldn't be there. You're the only one that knows what you did. Un-do it. You changed the `Name` to `"Identity"`, but the text is still the same. You probably also changed the file name, without considering the consequences.

Comment: @user9938 Ok I did that, but it's still blank, so odd.

Comment: In VS menu, click Build => Clean => Rebuild.

Comment: Copied your code and found no problem in showing the form. Probably the problem is not here but where you try to show the form.

Comment: @Steve that's strange, where would I go to alter it? I'm a beginner so I don't always know what part affects what in the whole scheme of things just yet.

Comment: @user9938 Ok I'll try that.

Comment: The posted code is incomplete; it lacks two button click handlers referenced by the designer.cs, but adding them in makes the code work normally for me. I cannot reproduce the complaint

Comment: I suggest you start a new project, make a new form called Identity, copy every line of code except the last 3 out of this post, and paste it over the top of every line of the new Identity.Designer.cs except the last 2 (thereby omitting the line `private EventHandler label1_Click;` which, as Jimi points out, is unexpected), then copy your struct and two button click handlers over (double click each button, paste the code etc) - you'll probably get up and running faster by starting this form over than by repeatedly banging your head on whatever is wrong with it.

Comment: @CaiusJard but aren't the button click handlers connected to the TWO buttons that I created? Why would it not work for me to just add them as you did? Aren't they already there? I'm still new to c#, so I don't fully grasp everything yet.

Comment: Did you find that in Program.cs that it still showed "Form1"? If so, the easiest thing may be to go back to "Program.cs", change `Application.Run(new Identity());` back to `Application.Run(new Form1());`. Then in Solution Explorer, right click `Identity.cs` and select rename. Rename it to `Form1.cs`. When prompted, "You are renaming a file..." click "No". Then right-click "Form1.cs" and select "Rename". Rename it to "Identity". This time, when prompted: You are renaming a file. Would you also like to perform a rename in this project of all references..." click YES.

Comment: @user9938 Ok I'll try it, I might have to re-do the project as Caius Jard pointed out perhaps, but I can try this first. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @CaiusJard hey, when I try to copy the lines from my old designer.cs into my new one, I keep getting error messages for my buttons saying like identity does not contain a definition for button2 and button1_click?

Comment: Copy the buttonX_Click methods from your old Identity.cs to your new one, then it will contain definitions for them

Comment: @CaiusJard in that case, don't I have to create new buttons in a new file? If I just copy the lines of codes for the buttons, will that be enough, if I create new buttons, will it still work?

Comment: @CaiusJard  I tried to copy the button methods from the old one to the new one, but the problem still occurs? What is the button method anyway, isn't it just for example in my identity.cs THIS;   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) . Or what specifically is it? And what should it replace or be put in place for? I can copy the exact code from my old identity.cs to my new one, even naming everything just the same but I still get the error in my identity.designer.cs Sorry if this seems like a simple matter and that I don't understand.

Comment: Alternative way then: open up the `Identity.Designer.cs` file, find the lines with errors and comment them out. Then you can open the visual form designer, double click the buttons and add new handler code in the `Identity.cs` file. If you don't comment the bad lines out in the `.designer.cs` out you won't be able to open the visual designer

Comment: Note, if you're about to say "But my file is called Form1.Designer.cs" then you've skipped the part of my last instructions where i said 'add a form called Identity' ... so that's Right click project Add New Item.. Form.. Named "Identity"

Comment: @CaiusJard hey!  I got it to work finally! Thank you, your solution to remove the ones with errors and comment them out and adding new handler codes worked.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment trail, you made a new solution, copied some select lines over from the problematic form's designer code, commented out some event handlers that were missing in the designer code, and then were able to load the designer and add the missing event handlers and their body code. The resulting form worked OK